# Submitting Assistant Action to Alpha channel returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: actions-on-google

We are no longer able to submit our action to the Alpha and/or Preview channels for testing.

**From the [Actions Console](https://console.actions.google.com):**

- Clicking the *Deploy* tab
- *Start New Release*
- Select 'Alpha' Channel
- Clicking *Submit*

Normally, the page would now refresh and show the draft version being deployed to Alpha.
Instead, we get this error: "Your submission of Version XX was denied"
[image: Your submission of Version XX was denied]
**Note**: This error appears immediately, the Action did not go through review and get denied; the submission itself failed. We're not getting any more error info on *why* the submission failed, and also didn't get any info by email. (Normally, when the Action gets reviewed and there's a problem, we get an email explaining what we should do to fix it)

When trying to deploy the Action from the [Google Actions SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions) (`gactions`), a similar error appears:

```
powershell
PS C:\src\google-action\definitions> gactions push
Pushing files in the project "gluco-check-prod" to Actions Console. This may take a few minutes.
Sending configuration files...
Waiting for server to respond...
Done. Files were pushed to Actions Console, and you can now view your project with this URL: 
https://console.actions.google.com/project/gluco-check-prod/overview. 
If you want to test your changes, run "gactions deploy preview", 
or navigate to the Test section in the Console.

PS C:\src\google-action\definitions> gactions deploy preview
Deploying files in the project "gluco-check-prod" to Actions Console for preview.
This may take a few minutes.
Sending configuration files...
Waiting for server to respond.
It could take up to 1 minute if your cloud function needs to be redeployed.  
[ERROR] Server did not return HTTP 200.
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error occurred"
  }
}
```

Again, there's no info other than this 500 Internal Server Error.

I have also tried deploying the exact same version that we have currently in Production, and the submission still fails.
Am I overlooking something, or is this an issue on Google's side?

Comment: Hey there - thanks for the report. We're investigating this issue and working on a resolution. We'll report back with updates as we learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Likewise, we've been unable to submit any releases to preview, alpha, beta or production channels for almost a week.

CLI throws 500 errors, website shows a blank page and all attempted submissions show up minutes later with "submission failed."

Emails to support under the topic Deployment Issues have gone unanswered as well, so there's no way to figure out what's going on or how to fix it.

Comment: Someone from the AoG team [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69729446/submitting-assistant-action-to-alpha-channel-returns-500-internal-server-error/69801466#comment123334796_69729446) in this thread and got back to me by email as well. Apparently it's an ongoing issue and they're busy investigating. As devs, I'm guessing we don't have many other options other than just waiting. But I believe this issue is also affecting some big customers (Sony). Hopefully that will increase priority.